# Lucene syntaz fuzzy phrase query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Currently my search executes a phrase query ton return results where the given search input matches each term in the exact order.

e.g.

**value:** `The lazy dogs`

**search 1:** `fields.\*.content:"lazy dogs"` - *matches*

**search 2:** `fields.\*.content:"dogs lazy"` - *doesn't match*

**search 3:** `fields.\*.content:"lazy dog"` - *doesn't match*

The constructed lucene syntax query that gets executed is:
`fields.\*.theValue:"lazy dogs"`

In the example above I would like search 3 to match the value as well, meaning I want to add some fuzziness to the entire phrase itself. I am limited to lucene (query string) syntax, is this possible?

Comment: Using the [classic query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description), with a Standard Analyzer, all three of your searches find the value `The lazy dogs`. So, nothing more is needed. You can also add a tilde `~` at the end of a phrase to provide some additional [word proximity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Proximity_Searches) searching - but your question does not appear to be asking about that. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: You can use [fuzzy searching](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Fuzzy_Searches) with individual terms, also - maybe that is more relevant here?

Comment: Sorry, I think the original formatting / example was confusing and have updated it to hopefully be clearer.

All three searches do not find the value because they are being sent as phrase queries, so the order matters. I am trying to avoid is fuzzy searching each term individually and instead fuzzy search the phrase itself.